# How to pass keyboard's dynamic in telegram bot?

Tags: php, bots, telegram

**Hi, I'm having trouble creating a dynamic keyboard for the telegram robot**
**I want to create my own ring with the keyboard in the picture below**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOIq8.jpg)

I have found the C # code but can't convert it to PHP code:

```
for (var Index = 1; Index < 17; Index++)
{
    cols.Add(new KeyboardButton("" + Index));
    if (Index%4 != 0) continue;
    rows.Add(cols.ToArray());
    cols = new List<KeyboardButton>();
}
rkm.Keyboard = rows.ToArray();
```

**One important note**

I have 40 numbers that I want to assign 40 buttons in a row to 4 buttons

```
$reply_markup = array('keyboard' => array(array('1','2','3','4'),  array('5','6','7','8'),....), 'resize_keyboard' => true);
```

But whatever I do, I can't do it
Thank you for helping me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `php` you must use two loop like this:

```
$rows = 10;
$columns = 4;
$keyboard = [];
for($i = 1;$i<=$rows;$i++){ // loop for create rows.
    $rowKeys = []; // reset row keys
    for($j = 1;$j<=$columns;$j++){ // loop for create columns.
        $rowKeys[] = ['text'=>$i*$j, 'callback_data'=>'key-'.($i*$j)]; // create button with callback data
    }
    $keyboard[] = $rowKeys;
}

$reply_markup = $keyboard;
```

Comment: Thanks ,PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in

Comment: sendMessage($chat_id, $message,json_encode($reply_markup));

Comment: I want to use `$reply_markup = array('keyboard' => array(array('1','2','3','4'),  array('5','6','7','8'),....), 'resize_keyboard' => true);sendMessage($chat_id, $message,json_encode($reply_markup));` not InlineKeyboard

Comment: @AbbasMohebbi so you can use this logic for that array you want.

Comment: Thanks
But this area can only be used on the InlineKeyboard

Comment: Thanks  Thanks  ttrasn